# PopoverPresentationController delegate methods not called

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

I have a class to construct a UIPopoverPresentationController in an empty swift file:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Popovers : NSObject, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    func presentLoginScreen() {
        // Presenting login Popover

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let loginScreen = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LogInScreen")

        let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.last!
        let height = window.screen.bounds.size.height
        let width = window.screen.bounds.size.width

        loginScreen.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        loginScreen.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(width * 0.85  , height * 0.35)

        let loginScreenPopover = loginScreen.popoverPresentationController
        loginScreenPopover?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.init(rawValue: 0)
        loginScreenPopover?.delegate = self
        loginScreenPopover?.sourceView = window.rootViewController?.view
        loginScreenPopover?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(window.screen.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(window.screen.bounds), 0, 0)

        window.rootViewController?.presentViewController(loginScreen, animated: true, completion: nil)

        let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)) as UIVisualEffectView
        let bounds = window.screen.bounds
        blur.frame = bounds
        blur.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        window.rootViewController!.view.addSubview(blur)

    }

    func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
    }

    func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
        // Remove blur layer
        print("method called")
        let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.last
        window?.subviews.last?.removeFromSuperview()


    }


}
```

But whenever I dismiss the PopoverPresentationController the delegate method `popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover` is never fired.

I have set the delegate of the loginScreenPopover to self and let the Popovers class inherit from the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate but neither seems to be working.

It is on an iPhone, if that is relevant to the question.

Comment: How did you dismiss the `popOverController`? If you dismiss it programmatically, `func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover` is not going to be fired

Comment: I did not dismiss it programatically, I tapped outside of the popover view

Comment: For me the problem was that, calling the PopoverViewController through a "PerformSegue" was always ignoring the delegates. Deleting the storyboard segue and manually assembling it and showing through presentViewController solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. In the ViewDidLoad() from the LogInScreen I set the delegate to:

```
self.popoverPresentationController.delegate = getPopovers()
```

Where the `getPopovers()` function is a function to retrieve the Popover object created somewhere else in the code. Now in my Popovers class I can conform to the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate and use those methods.